# How does CoffeeScript handle Asynchronous Calls?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, coffeescript

Current Asynchronous JavaScript calls require us to use a Callback function. This can lead to "rabbit hole" code when you need to make a 2nd Ajax call based on data returned in a 1st Ajax call.

There have been attempts to make Asynchronous JavaScript calls without the use of Callbacks. Google, Narative.js. The goal being more manageable and readable code.

My question is, How does CoffeeScript handle Asynchronous JavaScript calls like Ajax? Are callbacks required or can Asynchronous calls be made without callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript doesn't offer any particular features geared toward asynchronicity, because this would necessarily cause a large gap between CoffeeScript code and the JavaScript output. See the discussion about the proposed `defer` syntax:

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/350

So, if you use CoffeeScript, you should deal with asynchronous behavior using the same idioms and libraries as in JavaScript. The difference is that your callbacks will be written as `-> ...` rather than `function() {...}`.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. I've been following that discussion. For what it is worth, I believe the defer feature would make CoffeeScript undeniable. @gfxmonk gave it a helluva go and I so commend him. He wrote a post on the defer proposition - every word was as if I had written it myself - I was taken back really. Handling asynchronous logic really is one of the most unintuitive features of JavaScript. For those of you interested in the article: http://gfxmonk.net/2010/07/04/defer-taming-asynchronous-javascript-with-coffeescript.html

Comment: Finals words are I wish this feature existed in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1):

Coffeescript is a language that some people think is clearer, more concise, and easier to write and read than Javascript.  Coffeescript compiles to Javascript, which then runs on a Javascript virtual machine.  At the end of the day, Coffeescript can only do what Javascript is capable of doing.

> How does CoffeeScript handle Asynchronous Calls?

Like Javascript.  If you want to use callbacks, use callbacks.  If you want to use Narative.js, use that.  If you want to use Jquery, use that.

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) (not coffee script specific) to make things more clear.

```
var firstCall = $.get 'stuff.json'
$.when(firstCall).then #make second call
```

Comment: Really feeling this. I've been looking into jQuery when last couple hours.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to adopt https://github.com/mirek/node-flat-flow approach to make call chain flat. It works very well with coffeescript.